# IllegalArgumentException when using @Autowired in test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, autowired

I have the below test class:

```
public class DecoderTest {
    
    @Autowired
    DecodeOutboundSbe decodeOutbound;
    
    /**
     * Test getSeqNo
     */
    @Test
    void testGetSeqNo() {
        
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(decodeOutbound,
                "seqNo",
                10);
        long seqNo = decodeOutbound.getSeqNo();
        assertEquals(10, seqNo);
    }
}
```

When I run the test it fails with:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either targetObject or targetClass for the field must be specified
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121)
> at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:173)
> at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:105)
> at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:89)
> at com.cme.pe.decoder.DecoderTest.testGetSeqNo(DecoderTest.java:33)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

This seems to be because `decodeOutbound` is `null`.

If I change `DecodeOutbound decodeOutbound` for `DecodeOutboundSbe decodeOutboundSbe = new DecodeOutboundSbe()` my test works. Am I doing something wrong with `@Autowired`?

Comment: how did you configure your test class?

Comment: Is your test class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: It is now. No change though.